# Replacing images in Django with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Hi StackOverflow Community

I am using Django to set up a mobile-friendly web-page. The page contains a series of images and a button. When you click the button one of those images should be replaced.

The problem:
I use the {% static 'img/Test1.jpg' %} tag in the HTML. This is only rendered correctly when the page loads.

```
<div class="container" id="top_container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- Major Row containing both the chat window and the autoring window -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 center-block">
            <h1>{{secretDisplay.secretTitle}}</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-ls-12 center-block" id="child"> <!-- Chat Window -->
                        <p contenteditable="true" class="chat_window" style="text-align:left">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div> <!-- This is where we will author the messages -->
                    <p contenteditable="true" class="col-ls-12 center-block write_window author_box">This is the test</p>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to replace the first image, but the following code doesn't work as Django only renders the {% static 'img/Test2.jpg' %} on page-load.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#about-btn").click( function(){
        $('.chat_window img').attr("src","{% static 'img/Test2.jpg'%}");
    });
});
```

Is there an elegant way to replace the image dynamically without having to provide jQuery with the absolute path?

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Thank you
M

Comment: Do you have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for that problem? Would be helpful.

Comment: Here it is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mnedelko/o11b683x/#&togetherjs=tVxsjlQ9ay) but I am not sure how this would help as fiddle would not be able to render the django tags, which I think might be what's the problem here.

Comment: Hi @saravanann. Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately that does not solve my problem as the tags are still rendered once before/ on page-load. My objective would be to have the image replaced and displayed dynamically after the page-load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Django only renders the {% static 'img/Test2.jpg' %} on page-load.

Django does **not** render template on page-load. Django renders it before page-load.

If you already know what path you want to paste, then no need for Django static tag:

```
$("#about-btn").click( function(){
    $('.chat_window img').attr("src","img/Test2.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Hi @donjiyor. Thank you for the suggestion. I considered this, but was wondering whether there was a more elegant solution out there that would allow me to continue using the Django tags opposed to the absolute path. The reason for this is that I may be required to change the path dynamically depending on user input later.